# AJAX Cascading Dropdowns ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a request form for work. The request deals with series of products. There are many series, so I am trying to filter them down by the product line that they are produced on. I am attempting this using cascading dropdown lists from Ajax. I know the script is working to a degree, because the default selected option changes to "Make Selection". However, the rest of the dropdown does not populate.

Here are the two dropdowns.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProductLine, new SelectList(Model.ProductLines, "Value", "Text"), "Select a Product Line", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 400px;", @id = "ProductLineID"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSeries, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select a Series", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SeriesID"})
```

The Ajax Script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $('#ProductLineID').change(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/SMRMaster/RequestForm/GetSeries',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            data: { id: $('#ProductLineID').val() },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#SeriesID').html('');
                $('#SeriesID').append($('<option>Make Selection</option>'));
                $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                    $('#SeriesID').append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The Controller.

```
public JsonResult GetSeries(string id)
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNOCMMITTED;");
        var productLineName = "";
        switch (Id)
        {
            case 0:
                productLineName = "Electric";
                break;
            case 1:
                productLineName = "Europe Gas";
                break;
            case 2:
                productLineName = "Gas";
                break;
            case 3:
                productLineName = "Miscellaneous";
                break;
            case 4:
                productLineName = "Water";
                break;
            default:
                productLineName = "Electric";
                break;
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> series = (from s in db.Series
                      where s.ProductLineName == productLineName
                      select new SelectListItem { Value = s.ProductLineName, Text = s.ProductLineName }).ToList();


        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public List<ProductLine> GetProductLines()
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
        var productLineList = (from p in db.ProductLines
                               select p).ToList();

        return productLineList;
    }


    public ActionResult RequestForm()
    {
        var count = 0;
        var productLineList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in GetProductLines())
        {
            productLineList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.ProductlineName, Value = count.ToString() });

        }
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
        var requestViewModel = new RequestViewModel { SMRMaster = new SMRMaster(), Engineers = GetEngineers(), ProductLines = productLineList };
        return View(requestViewModel);
    }
```

And the view model.

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductLines { get; set; }
    public string SelectedProductLine { get; set; }
    public SMRMaster SMRMaster { get; set; }
    public List<string> Engineers { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engineer is required.")]
    public string SelectedEngineer { get; set; }
    public List<Series> Series { get; set; } 
    public string SelectedSeries { get; set; }
}
```

I do not know where the error is coming from. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I do not know where the error is coming from* What error? and where?

Comment: did you place debug point here and checked  **series** has any values **return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)**

Comment: check whether the Getseries is returning the value. put a debugger and  try to findout .whether its empty or filled

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're linking to this question instead providing of .NET fiddle link. To OP: Are you checked the console yet? Is that validation message appear in view?

Comment: Open your devtools (F12 on chrome. check the console tab, If no errors there, check network tab and check the call to your server was made and the response status is 200 OK)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Oops - [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Some extra notes for OP. 1. Using `new SelectList()` in the DropDownListFor() to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is pointless extra overhead. 2. The parameter in the method should be `GetSeries(int id)` - let the `DefaultModelBinder` do it job. 3. Return an anonymous object containing just the 2 properties you need (there is no point sending back all the other properties of `SelectListItem` that you never use).

Comment: @SaurinVala When I place a breakpoint on the return Json, it never actually breaks during debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague helped me solve this problem. Firstly, the Ajax script was using the wrong URL. Secondly, my controller functions were unnecessarily complicated.

Here is the updated AJAX script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $('#ProductLine').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SMRMaster/GetSeries',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            data: { productLine: $('#ProductLine').val() },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#SeriesID').html('');
                $('#SeriesID').append($('<option>Make Selection</option>'));
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    var optionData = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>';
                    $(optionData).appendTo('#SeriesID')
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the updated Controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetSeries(string productLine)
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
        List<SelectListItem> series = (from s in db.Series
                                        where s.ProductLineName == productLine
                                        select new SelectListItem { Value = s.SeriesName, Text = s.SeriesName }).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public List<ProductLine> GetProductLines()
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
        var productLineList = (from p in db.ProductLines
                               select p).ToList();
        return productLineList;
    }


    public ActionResult RequestForm()
    {
        var productLineList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in GetProductLines())
        {
            productLineList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.ProductlineName, Value = item.ProductlineName });
        }
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
        var requestViewModel = new RequestViewModel { SMRMaster = new SMRMaster(), Engineers = GetEngineers(), ProductLines = productLineList };
        return View(requestViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(result, function (i, item) {
          var optionData = '<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + obj.Text + '</option>';
             $(optionData).appendTo('#SeriesID')      
});
```

Or debug and see what's your response from server.