# How can C# use a WebView to send/receive data with Java Script that embbeded at html page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

We are try to develop a login system. My partner develop the server side html page with Java Script. I need to develop a C# using WebView to connect to Server HTML page that embedded JavaScript.

How can C# use WebView to send/receive data with JavaScript that embedded at HTML page? for example ,how C# or webview send serial number ,username and password to JS. How can I receive success or fail from JS that embedded in html,

I need a C# example code and more description. I don't need to connect with a database, but I need send/received data with JS. I am not good at English. I had less experience at C# and JavaScript. I do not know how to start. I am not sure and not clear to know how to start? Please help ....Thanks

The HTML and JavaScript are as below :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel=icon href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/favicon.ico><title>iot_webview</title><link href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/css/chunk-369f5a7b.c806a610.css rel=prefetch><link href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/js/chunk-369f5a7b.65277440.js rel=prefetch><link href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/css/app.4fc83482.css rel=preload as=style><link href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/js/app.c652be61.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/js/chunk-vendors.cc830bf6.js rel=preload as=script><link href=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/css/app.4fc83482.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but iot_webview doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript><div id=app></div><script src=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/js/chunk-vendors.cc830bf6.js></script><script src=/ubiqconn_ota_development/dist/js/app.c652be61.js></script></body></html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514404/net-mvc-ajax-post-error-403-forbidden/50515345#50515345  . Check this one out. I have answered earlier. It might help

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50500883/ajax-cascading-dropdowns-asp-net-mvc/50501106#50501106